# Random access file visual basic 2012

Tags: vb.net, file

I am having trouble making my record number unique in visual basic 2012 the code i have so far is overwriting the file that was previously saved??

my module

```
Imports System.IO
Module AssModule
    Structure employee
        ' Public Name As String
        ' Public ID As String

        <VBFixedString(30)> Dim name As String ' vb fixed string
        <VBFixedString(5)> Dim id As String ' vb fixed string



    End Structure

    Structure transaction
        <VBFixedString(5)> Dim id As String ' vb fixed string
        Dim time As Date
        <VBFixedString(3)> Dim type As String ' vb fixed string
    End Structure

    ' Public fileSize As Integer = Len(index)
    ' Public Staff(100) As employee ' staff as new name for eployeee structure


    Public myEmployee As employee

    Public r As Integer = 5
    Public fileNumber As Integer = FreeFile()
    Public mySizerecordnumber As Integer = Len(myEmployee)
    Public recordNumber As Integer



    Public index As Byte



    Public Sub setRecordNumber()
        Dim n As Byte = 0
        FileOpen(fileNumber, "binData.dat", OpenMode.Random, OpenAccess.Read)
        While Not EOF(fileNumber)
            n = n + 1
            FileGet(fileNumber, myEmployee, n)
        End While
        recordNumber = n
        FileClose(fileNumber)
    End Sub



End Module
```

add employee button

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    For n = 0 To 3
        FileOpen(fileNumber, "binData.dat", OpenMode.Random, OpenAccess.Write, , mySizerecordnumber)
        myEmployee.id = txtID.Text
        myEmployee.name = txtName.Text
        recordNumber = recordNumber + 1
        FilePut(fileNumber, myEmployee, recordNumber)
        FileClose(fileNumber)
    Next
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: what exactly you want???Please mention in detail

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's break down your `btnSave_Click` function.

For 0 to 3, each time, you: open the file, read it, put the result in myEmployee, then put it back in the file and close.

What you want to do (I think) is to save the new employee at the end of your file

You should open your file, move to the end, and save your new record:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    setRecordNumber()
    FileOpen(fileNumber, "binData.dat", OpenMode.Random, OpenAccess.Write, , mySizerecordnumber)
    myEmployee.id = txtID.Text
    myEmployee.name = txtName.Text
    FilePut(fileNumber, myEmployee, recordNumber)
    FileClose(fileNumber)
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```